# counter of served clients in a simple server using python + twisted

Tags: python, twisted

Im using twisted to make a simple server that accepts multiple connections and i want to count the numbers of clients who have been connected. This counting im doing in the factory (as is logical) using clientConnectionMade() but doesn't update the value of the counter, really i dont know where it is my mistake. I appreciate a little help.

My Server code: (also in http://bpaste.net/show/26789/)

```
 import socket
 import datetime
 from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
 from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):

def connectionMade(self):
    print "New client connected"

def dataReceived(self, data):
    print "Msg from the client received"
    if data == "datetime":
       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       self.transport.write("Date and time:")
       self.transport.write(str(now))
    elif data == "clientes":
       self.transport.write("Numbers of clients served: %d " % (self.factory.numClients))
    else:
       self.transport.write("msg received without actions")

class EchoFactory(Factory):

protocol = Echo

    def __init__(self):
        self.numClients = 0

    def clientConnectionMade(self):
       self.numClients = self.numClients+1

def main():
factory = EchoFactory()
factory.protocol = Echo
reactor.listenTCP(9000,factory)
reactor.run()

 # this only runs if the module was *not* imported
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Doesnt show any error, just doesnt update the counter 'numClients' and i dont know why.

Thanks

Comment: This compiles? Your spacing is not correct...

Answer (score 1):

clientConnectionMade (where you increment self.numClients) is [not a valid method on the Factory class](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.Factory.html), so it will never be called by the framework.

Calling self.factory.numClients += 1 from inside of your Echo.connectionMade() method would work:

```
class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "New client connected"
        self.factory.numClients += 1
```

You could also override your Factory's buildProtocol() method to do something similar.

Comment: thanks fmoo but doesnt work because the connectionmade is called just once, so the numclients update to 1 and remains there. In fact that was my first code and i think the clients counting must be in the factory.